# Is $V = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:\ x+y >1 \}$ a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove whether the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are subspaces :

(a)

$$V = \{(x,y,z)\ \in \mathbb{R}^3:\ x+y >1 \ \},$$

I think that this is not a subspace as the zero vector does not fulfill the "x+y >1".

However, how do I show that this is closed under addition and closed under scalar multiplication (or if they are not, how do I show that)?

Comment: You don't really have to prove that. It's enough to show that one axiom or property fails.

Comment: Multiplying anything by zero gives you the zero vector

Answer (score 2):

By definition a subset $V\subset U$ must fulfill **all** of the 3 conditions below to be called a subspace of the vector space $U$:

- It must contain a zero vector.
- It must be closed under addition.
- It must be closed under scalar multiplication.

You successfully pointed that the subset in question doesn't fulfill the first condition, hence it isn't a subspace, and you aren't required to see whether the other conditions are fulfilled.

---

Assume that — for the sake of mathematical curiosity — you wanted to see whether $U$ fulfilled the other conditions. Let $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)\in V$ and let $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)\in V$, then $v_1+v_2>1$ and $u_1+u_2>1$. Hence $(v_1+u_1)+(v_2+u_2)>2$. Can you then show that this means that $v+u\in V$? Next, consider $\lambda v=(\lambda v_1,\lambda v_2,\lambda v_3)$. For it to be in $V$ it must satisfy $\lambda v_1+\lambda v_2=\lambda(v_1+v_2)>1$. Is this true for all $\lambda\in\bf R$? If not, what can we conclude?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. It is not a subspace, for the reason you mentioned.
As for being closed under scalar-multiplication: suppose you multiply a vector in your set by $-1$. What do you see?
Your set $\it{is}$ however closed under addition. Can you prove it?

Comment: What I've done so far is:                                                                                             Let U = (x1, y1, z1) and V = (x2,y2,z2)                                                                      U + V  = x1 + x2 + y1 +y2 +z1 +z2. How do I go on from there?

Comment: Ok, now you know that x1+y1 > 1 and also x2 + y2 > 1. So, what can you say about (x1+x2) + (y1+y2) ? Is it also greater than 1? And if so, what does it mean?